# Category of partitions of an interval

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory, riemann-integration, monotone-functions, partitions-for-integration

Revisiting the definition of Riemann integral, Carla noticed that we can define partitions of an interval categorically: given a (nondegenerate) interval $[a,b]$ seen as an ordered set with top and bottom, partitions are just monotone functions that preserve tops and bottoms from $n$ to $[a,b]$, for $n\geq 2$.

Amusingly, morphisms of partitions seem to correspond to refinements of partitions. Has anyone noticed this before, and if yes, is there a reference? (If not, did Carla make a mistake?)

(Carla is allowing partitions like $(0,0,1)$ of $[0,1]$, just like Rudin does. It might be possible to disallow those by considering only strictly monotone morphisms).

Edit: Also, coproducts seem to correspond to common refinements.

Edit 2: A moment of thought shows this is stupid: the partitions $(0,1,3)$ and $(0,2,3)$ of $[0,3]$ are isomorphic, which shows this is the wrong way to think about partitions of an interval.

Comment: Carla, not sure I follow completely. Partition over a fixed closed bounded interval can be partially order by inclusion. The Riemann integral may then be defined as a limit over nets. (J. Kelly’s General Topology has an exercise along these lines). Then again, maybe this is not what you are expecting as an answer.

Comment: @OliverDíaz That might be a good way to do this. My last edit should show that the original idea was bad.